# Electric vs Electrical vs Electronic

Tags: terminology

I want to know if the words electric, electrical, and electronic can be used interchangeably. They all seem to mean about the same thing... Any suggestions?

Comment: If followed by the word "theory," sure. But 'electronic' generally implies some kind of  processing, decision making or control abilities that you might not find in electrical appliances. An electric waffle iron has a sensor and a thermostat, but an electronic watch can have a four function calculator and synchronize with Greenwich atomic clocks. Of course, those are really broad generalizations.

Comment: I would claim that _electric_ and _electrical_ relate to the use of electricity but _electronic_ relates to the use of the electron, initially as it was used in vacuum tubes, and later in semiconductor diodes and transistors.

Comment: I think the *usage* today of these words is largely based on experience, culture, and opinion. For a pedantic answer on the *meaning* of the words, I would ask this on [English.SE](http://english.stackexchange.com/). However among engineers, I find interchangeability is more common. (I even [asked about the site's name](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/q/2620/2028) based on my interpretation of *electrical* versus *electronic*.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Electric" and "electrical" mean exactly the same thing, and apply to anything that uses electricity, but mostly used for systems involving "passive" components — a battery or generator, motors, resistive loads, inductors and transformers, capacitors and maybe even rectifiers and relays.

"Electronic" is a term that is generally reserved for systems that incorporate "active" (electron) devices such as vacuum tubes or transistors — any device that can be said to have "gain", or the ability to proportionally control a large voltage or current using a small voltage or current.

Comment: ...electric engineer?

Comment: @JasonChen: It isn't idiomatic, but it means the same thing as "electrical engineer". Although I suppose it might imply a engineer who runs on electricity; i.e., a robot engineer. :-)

Answer (score 4):

I would not expect a person who works mostly with massive electric motors at steel mills and oil-cooled transformers the size of a Fiat 500 to call themselves an "Electronic Engineer", but an "Electrical Engineer" might work with microscopic 1005 parts or much larger stuff.

The reason is that historically electronics developed from electrical engineering, so it could be considered a subset or specialty, in some contexts.

I don't think it's normal to speak of an "Electric Engineer" unless you're referring to her or his dynamic personality (so it would be rather rare).

Answer (score 2):

For me some of the differences can be categorized as:

**Electrical** is more of an Electrician term.  IE Electrical system, Electrical installation ect ect.  Typically when I here the word Electrical I think of Pipe, Wire and major components such as lights, switches and relays.

**Electric** is a general term describing the source of the system.  As in Electric versus Hydraulic or pneumatic.

**Electronic** In general industry Electronic usually has something to do with semiconductors such as transistors, SCRs, diodes or semiconductor chips.  One example that comes to mind is Fluorescent light ballasts.  Going back 20 years ago almost all light ballasts were some type of simple transformer.  When these ballasts became designed similar to switching DC power supplies, reducing the size and cost - they became known as *electronic light ballasts*.